# Do assemblies have an initialization and/or termination routine?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I am trying to find a bug in my application; an unhandled exception. It seems like the exception is somewhere independtly from my code triggered. The only explanation i could find is, that the assembly i use executes some code that triggers the exception.

So do assemblies have an initialization and/or termination routine or something similiar?

Comment: When is the assembly terminated??

Comment: The full message i get is: "System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt. 
bei Unify.SQLBase.Data.SQLBaseCommand.Dispose 
bei Unify.SQLBase.Data.SQLBaseCommand.Finalize"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
  bei Unify.SQLBase.Data.SQLBaseCommand.Dispose
  bei Unify.SQLBase.Data.SQLBaseCommand.Finalize
```

Yes, this is a very nasty exception.  It is raised by the finalizer of the SQLBaseCommand class.  Which will happen when the finalizer thread runs.  This is completely asynchronous from your code, it can strike at any point in time.  The CLR will immediately terminate your program.

This is rather a nasty bug in the database provider you are using, SQLBase by the sound of it.  Hard to believe they ship a provider with a bug like that.  Short from looking for an update for that provider, take a good look at the SqlCommand objects that you create in your code.  If none of this helps then you really need support from the vendor (Unify).

Comment: That's a good point. It may be an actual bug in the provider.

Comment: Thanks for your awnswer. That was the kind of information I needed. I suspected it being a bug because like you said, the exception seemed to be triggered asynchronous from my code. I already contacted Unify, but they said they needed a sampleprogram. Do you  have any idea how to reproduce this bug?

Comment: Why don't you tell them that this bug is highly visible on a web site that many of their potential customers visit?  Send them a link to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a handler to the appdomain:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This will now get called if any exception is thrown, and from there you can get the call stack. If you're running it under the debugger, go to Debug menu -> Exceptions and Tick "Thrown" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions. This will break the debugger when ever an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

No, .NET assemblies doesn't have initialization or termination routine

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that C# does not support module initializers, although they *are* supported in the CLR v2. It would require modification of the IL to create one. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx.

However, I doubt that your exception is caused by code run in a module initializer. It looks like the error is happening in SQLBaseCommand.Dispose upon Finalize. So, a couple of questions:

1. Are you disposing all SQLBaseCommand and related objects that implement IDisposable? If not, then perhaps the SQLBaseCommand class does not implement finalization correctly and you could avoid that by Disposing it yourself (which is the best practice anyway).
2. Look at your population and usage of SQLBaseCommand objects. Are they well formed according to the API? Are you using them in the correct patterns?
3. Get a tool such as Red Gate's  Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to view the decompiled SQLBaseCommand C# code. Look at the Finalize and Dispose methods. What is it expecting to be not null that you could have omitted initialization of, or affected in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the class constructor (or a static constructor) as long as you put the appropriate safegaurds in place.

You want to make sure that once MQ has been registered you don't try to do it again. You also want to make sure that if the registration fails, your constructor doesn't throw an exception but sets the class state in such a way that the class is created but not usable. Throwing an exception in the constructor will result in a very ambiguous "Type initialization failed" error message.

The better way would be to create a singleton class that manages the relationship with MQ. The singleton is instantiated once in your class constructor. It would need to provide an explicit "register" method, and any other methods that access MQ would be part of this singleton and can take advantage of the register method implicitly. The benefit here is that everytime you make a call to MQ, the system verifies that MQ has been registered, and if not registers it before making the call.

Comment: Class constructors are not run on assembly load.